# Regular Expression: replace everything but not a specific word

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to perform a simple `replace();` method in `JavaScript` where I'd like to remove every class from an `HTML element` except a specific one, how can I do it?

I tried this without success:

```
<div id="my_div" class="hello letsgo baby is_checked cool">Gordon Freeman</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert ($(#my_div).attr("class").replace (/^(is_checked)$/, ""));
    // id'like it returns "is_checked" or "" to work like a boolean;
});
</script>
```

Comment: could you give some examples of what should happen and what shouldn't happen?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been too hasty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to alert `is_checked` when it's there, right? Try using [.hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($("#my_div").hasClass("is_checked")) {
        alert("is_checked");
    }
    else {
        alert("");
    }
});
```

If you just want to know whether an element has a certain class on it, this returns true or false telling you exactly that:

```
$("#my_div").hasClass("is_checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove every class except a specific one? You can use jQuery's `attr()` method and define the class specifically:

```
$('#my_div').attr('class','is_checked');
```

Here's an example of this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/decHw/

Also important to note that if you wish to select an element in jQuery by its id, you need to wrap it in quotes. You have:

```
$(#my_div)
```

It should be:

```
$('#my_div')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('is_checked') {
      $(this).removeClass();
      $(this).addClass('is_checked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(this).hasClass('is_checked'))
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('is_checked');
else
    $(this).removeClass();
```